# C# XML Serialization remove unwanted information

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

Hello would anyone know how to remove the hyperlink thats part of my countrydata node?
Also does anyone know how to remove the data identifier for the CountryName node? (Text)

```
      <CountryData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

      <CountryName Type="Text">United States of America</CountryName>
```

I am using the xml serializer class and settings class
 XmlWriterSettings 
  XmlWriter

Comment: Any reason besides making it more beautiful?

Comment: Storing it in a DB dont want to take up any more space than i need to even though they are just chars.

Comment: Than, any reason why you dont store it as blob/binary instead of string?

Comment: not my architecture